# Components don't hide after I'm logged in using authService

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make the login and register link disappear from the navbar when a person is logged in. I'm following a tutorial on Youtube to fix this issue, but it's not working.

```
    <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a  [routerLink]= "['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a> </li>
          <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active'] " [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a  [routerLink]= "['/profile']">Profile</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a  [routerLink]= "['/login']">Login</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"> <a  [routerLink]= "['/register']">Register</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()"><a (click)="onLogOutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
```

At this point it's hiding the logout and profile at all times, isn't appearing when I'm logged in.

The Auth.service.ts looks like this :

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
authToken: any;
user: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  } 

  loggedIn(){
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }
  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }
}
```

Comment: `tokenNotExpired()` these method what return in your component?

Comment: where do you use method storeUserData(token, user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `token` instead of `id_token` in `storeUserData` function.

Have a look for detailed explanation [info](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/334#issuecomment-375060157)

Answer (score 0):

`token` is the default name which the below libraries access in localstorage. if you define your own name then you can follow below methods

`angular2-jwt` is deprecated go with `@auth0/angular-jwt`

defined you token getter in JwtModule `@auth0/angular-jwt`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
}

JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
    whitelistedDomains: ['example.com'],
    blacklistedRoutes: ['example.com/examplebadroute/']
  }
})
```

If you still want to use the old one go for `angular2-jwt`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt

```
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```